# convert video files to flv format in c#

Tags: c#, video, transcoding

How do I get video file from user and convert it into flv format?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is some example code and a  C#/.NET library that will convert audio to video, and vice versa using an FFMpeg wrapper. It's explained here:

http://ivolo.mit.edu/post/Convert-Audio-Video-to-Any-Format-using-C.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A solution to have multimedia support that converts virtually ANYTHING you throw at it is to use FFmpeg and MEncoder, you'll have quite a good input/output support:

- Input Image Sequence: jpg, pgm, png, ppm (with sequentially numbered-ONLY filenames)
  having the same filename numbered-ONLY format. Example: 0001.jpg --up to--> 0999.jpg
  note that this format will NOT work name_0001.jpg --up to--> name_0999.jpg  (take out name_)
- Input Video format: 3gp, 3g2, amv, asf, avi, dat, dvr-ms, fli, flc, flv, m2ts, mpg, mkv, mov
  m4v, mp4, nsv, ogm, qt, rm(vb), str, swf, ts, trp, ty, ty+, tmf, viv, vob, wmv ..
- Input Audio format: aac, ac3, amr, flac, mmf, m4a, mp2, mp3, mpc, ogg, ra, wav, wma ..
- Input AviSynth Script Files: avs.   To write a script and specify advanced encoding commands using AviSynth scripts!

(taken from [SUPER's website](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html))

NOTE: it has MUCH more support than "just" that. those are just some of the capabilities!! :D

Comment: Do you know where I can get a list of the supported output formats in MEncoder? Does it support `.amv` output?

Comment: @Shimmy I've been encoding in Linux for some time, and I recommend ffmpeg only. There's a package for virtually any distribution, and I managed to encode and decode from the formats I wanted just by reading the `--help` (didn't even had to read a man page!). As for `.amv` files, I had problems encoding to a similar "`.smv`" format, but look here: http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/

Comment: thank you so much for your input. Please check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129608/amv-video-encoder-converter