# .AMV video encoder/converter?

Tags: .net, c, video, video-encoding

I'm looking for a converter that can encode input files to [amv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMV_video_format) format output.

I've found [this](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/) project, but it looks somewhat outdated and not maintained. And the problem of that is that it supports a very limited variety of input file types.

Do you know of a solid and reliable amv encoder (any API or tool that can be invoked from .NET), or can you recommend on the one I mentioned?

**UPDATE**

I use FFmpeg for my application for all other types, the problem is that the .AMV format which is a key output file in my app, is not supported by FFmpeg at all.

**UPDATE**

Anyone has any idea if and how I can merge the outdated amv-codec suggested above with the official FFmpeg?

### Update

Are you a C developer willing to contribute?
Please refer to [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2011/05/17/silverlight-5-beta-imarkupextension-lt-t-gt-and-staticextension.aspx) ticket, it looks like an easy task for a decent C developer.

Comment: there is no such library in production quality... it can be implemented on top of some low-level functions found in commercial libraries... is that an option ?

Comment: @Yahia, the job has to be done. So I believe if I don't have any choice commercial resource are also considerable, the question is how do I invoke it from .NET if I all I know is .NET.

Comment: Please see my answer below... HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finally!!!

AMV is now officially a part of the new FFmpeg version 9.0 (Harmony), go ahead and download it if you're here looking for it:

http://ffmpeg.org

Answer (score 1):

.AMV is a proprietary video format that seems to be used for some Chinese MP4 and S1 MP3 players. 
There doesn't seem to be any alternative, atleast not for FFmpeg, other than [amv-codec-tools](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/) which you have already linked yourself.

Are there any issues with using the amv-codec-tools besides their age? If they work for you and suit your purposes, why not use them or contribute to them?

**Edit:** Regarding updating the outdated code with the latest FFmpeg, you could checkout the FFmpeg revision which they used as a base ([this one I believe](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=9dceaa923e04dacf6968203ce83cbbe0e3b16dbd)), patch their changes in, then update your checked out copy to the latest and greatest FFmpeg revision.

Comment: The problem with that tool is that the FFmpeg version it uses is really outdated, it's used as an alternative to FFmpeg, not as an addition, that's mainly the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your update. The problem is I don't know C at all, do you believe I'll still be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment above there is no production-quality library for this out there...

You will need to implement it on top of some low-level functions available in some commercial libraries...

To do that you will need a format description... there is no official one... AMV is used as a term for two formats (based on AVI as a container, called MTV and ALIAVI etc.) - the following link should give you a good starting point:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMV_video_format
- http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=AMV
- http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/wiki/AmvDocumentation
- http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/
- http://blog.rot13.org/2007/08/amv_free_decoder_works.html
- http://www.mathematik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kremer/aliavi.html
- http://groups.google.com/group/amv-codec-tools/browse_thread/thread/3afc2809797c1109
- http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Microsoft_IMA_ADPCM

Based on the above links and as many sample files you can get you should be able to create a rather good description of the format(s).

Then you can use one or more of the following libraries to develop a codec for it/them:

- http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia-suite.htm?linkid=top (can help with the [MJPEG](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/mjpeg.htm) part)
- http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Category:IMA_ADPCM_Audio_Codecs
- http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx
- http://www.visioforge.com/video-edit-sdk.html and/or http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk.html

The libraries I mentioned are all accessible from .NET although you should think about implementing the "heavy lifting" in native code (for performance reasons)...

Comment: Any additional info will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Shimmy additional information is a rather wide field - what kind of additional information are you looking for ?

Comment: Anything that will make it easier for me to integrate the AMV converter in my .NET app that currently uses FFmpeg for conversion. I'm afraid I'll have to convert some files twice if they ate not supported in the amv-codec-tools project, its underlying FFmpeg version is very outdated, any suggestions to avoid / how to / best practices on double conversion (i.e. intermediate format etc.)

Comment: @Shimmy What I described above is NOT to use the amv-codec-tools but take them among other things as an inspiration and write your own AMV "codec" on top of the libraries I listed. When you write your own you can integrate as well as you need/want...

Comment: I still didn't find a solution to my issue, but I did find a clue tho. Do you know C? Well I don't, and if you do, I'm sure that you'll be able to help me within just a couple of minutes if you have experience with C projects and *Makefile*s. I think it **is** possible to merge these two projects and combine them into on ffmpeg executable. Please checkout [this](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fffmpeg) link, I have to find a way to update the current FFmpeg source with the up-to-date FFmpeg, and compile it. If I read the map properly --next comment--->>>

Comment: <<<--- Continuing prev. comment --- that should be the most easy to implement and ultimate solution to my whole FFmpeg+AMV issue. Can you please help me out in exchange to the 60+ rep. you earned from this answer - or just for free if you prefer it this way :)

Comment: @Shimmy I know C but didn't use it for someabout 8-10 years... sorry, but can't help you with merging there... ffmpeg has some active forums, someone there might be able to help you out with that...

Comment: yesterday FFmpeg published a new version that supports muxing and demuxing of AMV, I posted an answer bellow. Thanks Yahia for all your effort. I learned a LOT from the links you provided me and thank god for every day I had to wait with this issue cuz I learned a tone of new stuff, thank you!

Comment: there is still a problem with the adpcm_amv codec, if you know C that should be an easy task to accomplish, please read [this](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/747).

Comment: @Shimmy that task is at least 8 hours of work (probably more with settingup  the needed development environment and testing etc.). I don't see any time soon where this would fit into my scheduled projects, sorry :-(

Comment: can you please contact me directly (via my blog) with a quote, I can try promote you for it, I'll talk to my manager.